# how to do nesting on MySQL returned results in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm making an app in angular and Node.js. I have data in two tables.

1. emails
2. email_attachments

suppose I have a row in `emails` table something like following:

```
id    | subject    | body       |
1     | text       | text body  |
```

and `email_attachments` table looks like:

```
email_id    | attachment_id    | attachment_name |
1           | 1                | attachment.pdf  |
1           | 2                | second.txt      |
```

Now when I query on these tables like this:

`SELECT e.*, ea.* FROM emails e
    LEFT JOIN email_attachments ea ON ea.email_id = e.id
    WHERE e.id='${id}'`

And it returns as many times repeated results as number of rows in `email_attachments`. But I want to get one row from `emails` table and then there should be array of objects appended at the end of result containing number of matched rows from `email_attachments`.

**Expected Output**

```
{
id: 1,
subject: text,
body: text body,
email_attachments:[
   {
     email_id: 1,
     attachment_id: 1,
     attachment_name: attachment.pdf
   },{
     email_id: 1,
     attachment_id: 2,
     attachment_name: second.txt
   }
  ]
}
```

so that I can show all the details and then loop over `email_attachment` object to show all attachments in an email. I already tried `node-mysql-nesting` package. It formats returned result as per my requirements, but it only add 1 rows from `email_attachments` table. I want to get all the matched rows in that object. `node-mysql-nesting` config options looks like this which I used.

```
var nestingOptions = [
    { tableName : 'emails', pkey: 'id', fkeys:[{table:'ea',col:'email_id'}]},
    { tableName : 'ea', pkey: 'email_id'}
];

var nestedRows = mysqlNesting.convertToNested(result, nestingOptions);
```

Is there any problem with nestingOtions or query needs to be modified? Any other solutions are also welcome as I just have concerns with output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to transform the format when you receive it in Node code.

```
let output = [];
rawRowsFromMySQL.forEach((row) => { // suppose rawRowsFromMySQL is an array of objects, keys are field names
  let data = output.find((document) => {
    return document.id === row.id;
  });
  let att = {
    email_id: row.id, // or .email_id
    attachment_id: row.attachment_id,
    attachment_name: row.attachment_name
  };
  if (data) {
    data.email_attachments.push(att);
  } else {
    data = {
      id: row.id,
      subject: row.subject,
      body: row.body,
      email_attachments: [att]
    };
    output.push(data);
  }
});
```

There might be a limited (see the linked doc) solution with [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), then Node's transition code would be quite simple; the query would look like:

```
SELECT
  e.id, e.subject, e.body,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT_WS(':', ea.email_id, ea.attachment_id, ea.attachment_name)
    SEPARATOR ','
  ) AS email_attachments
  FROM emails e
  LEFT JOIN email_attachments ea ON ea.email_id = e.id
  WHERE xxx
  GROUP BY e.id
```

Then your Node code would replace:

```
let output = rawRowsFromMySQL.map((row) => {
  row.email_attachments = row.email_attachments.split(',').map((att) => {
    let fields = att.split(':');
    return {
      email_id: fields[0],
      attachment_id: fields[1],
      attachment_name: fields[2]
    };
  });
})
```

You could even play with `CONCAT`/`CONCAT_WS` to have `email_attachments` in a JSON format, but I'm too lazy to write it down here... Anyway: latter is funnier, former is safer. ;)